# MS Excel - How to compare 2 columns for almost duplicate values and if equal, insert a 3rd column to the 4th

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have 2 tables. One table has email ids and Website urls & the other table has website urls with other essential information regarding them.

[Click here for screenshot of my requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RHbw.png)

Now, I need to cross reference the 2 tables and merge the email ids to the respective website urls. Atleast the almost similar website urls.

**Pictorial representation:**

```
Table 1:                       Table 2:
Website Urls                   Email ids                  Website Urls  
http://example.com             ...                        ....
..                             ...                        ....
..                             email@example.com          http://www.example.com 
..                             ...                        ....
```

NOTE: Even if I copy the 2nd table and paste it in first table, the values WON'T FALL ON THE SAME ROW.

Thanks in advance and have a nice day ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Try using vlookup with the match flag as true
`=vlookup(D2,A2:B8,2,TRUE)`

D2 is the value to be searched in table a2:b8 and retrieve second column value corresponding to it, with Approx(TRUE flag) match.

just make another column parallel to website URL,and substitute the https:// and www. with "" like

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2,"https://",""),"www.","")
```

where B2 is the cell having the URL and drag down the table,do similar thing for Table 2,and then use

```
=VLOOKUP(D2,A2:B8,2,FALSE)
```

with Exact flag.

```
     Table 1                   Table 2  
Website | E-mail        WebSite  | E-mail
```

Re-arrange in this order and try the vlookup formula for approximate,it should definately work.

Comment: Thanks but What I am trying to do is to get email ids only straight of their respective website urls when it is present in the 2nd table (i.e in another column). I am using something like =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2, B2:D500, 3, TRUE),""). But I don't get the email ids (Column E) straight to the respective website (column B)

Comment: A screenshot probably will be more helpful.But,so far what i understood,my solution should suffix your problem. Because if you want to pull exact data,the matching column should have atleast one column with exact values.

Comment: Added a screenshot in the original question as link. Kindly see to it and let me know if you need anything else. Thanks for your help

Comment: Try with FALSE flag first,later for the values failing you can try with TRUE Flag.

Comment: Did you see the screenshot image mate? If so, what might be the formula in that case?

Comment: actually for vlookup the lookup value should be on left,and in searched table the lookup value should be in the first column,but in screenshot it was not the case,dats why

Comment: I could insert the 2nd table's data whenever I want. I could insert them in the first. But which will work to get the email ids from the 2nd table get near the respective website urls in the 1st table by comparing it with 2nd table website urls.